# Form input type="date" in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to have a date input for a form. I know this only works in some browsers:

```
<input type="date" name="birth_day"/>
```

Is there a convenient method for this in Ruby on Rails? The [documentation for the various form elements](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) list many other input types, but I don't see anything for dates:

- email_field
- number_field
- phone_field
- range_field
- search_field
- telephone_field
- text_field

I know about date_select, that's not what I want. I want the above HTML output. I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.2.13. Is there possibly a `date_field` in Ruby on Rails 4? Or another way to do this?

Comment: I can't assure you but I think that this has been added in Rails 4: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5016

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can see the lastest [docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-date_field) that the `date_field` helper provide that. That seems a functionality from Rails 4.

Example from docs:

```
date_field("user", "born_on")
# => <input id="user_born_on" name="user[born_on]" type="date" />
```

Comment: Looks like it's time to upgrade to RoR 4!

Answer (score 5):

For older versions of Rails I believe you can use:

```
.text_field(type: 'date')
```

Comment: You can!  And for text_field_tag its: `text_field_tag :name, nil, type: :date` (where nil is the default value... you can put something else there if you have a default value) - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag